# How can store array value in database table in Zend framework?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

$array = Array
    (
        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => course
                [1] => course
            )

```
    [c_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => mca
            [1] => bca
        )

    [year] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013
            [1] => 2010
        )

    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => pursuing
            [1] => completed
        )

    [entity_type_rm_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

i am using:
foreach($array as $row){
how to create this array to store in db table?
}

table name

```
entity_type_rm_courses
```

and table columns

```
id  | entity_type_rm_id | type | c_name | year | statue
```

i want to set values like this

```
id | entity_type_rm_id | type   | c_name | year | statue
--- ------------------- -------- -------- ------ ---------
1  |       1           | course | mca    |2013  | pursuing
2  |       1           | course | bca    |2010  | completed
```

i want to use createRow() method to insert record in table

```
$courseRow = $courseTable->createRow($Course);
$courseRow->save();

$courseRow = $courseTable->createRow($Certification);
$courseRow->save();
```

Comment: What is not working? What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your array matches the code, Where is the array coming from, and where are $Course and $Certification being built?

Does the following work?

```
$course = array('type'=>'course', 'c_name'=>'mca', 'year'=>2012, 'status'=>'completed');

$courseRow = $courseTable->createRow($course);
$courseRow->save();
```

Comment: i want to know how to create array like:  $course = array('type'=>'course', 'c_name'=>'mca', 'year'=>2012, 'status'=>'completed');
when i am using foreach($array as $row) { }

Comment: probably best to edit your original question with more detail and try and get it reopened

Answer (score 0):

While nothing is clear from your question's body, to store array in database, use serialize(). Serialize converts PHP variables to a string form so that it can be easily stored. unserialize() reverses the process.

Comment: Unless the OP is going to store objects in a database, I'd highly recommend using `json` as opposed to `serialize`. Makes the values much easier to work with if (s)he wants to use them in JavaScript, for example, or in any other language.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Thats very correct. Thanks for that Colin...